# Why Will This Compile?

Tags: java, helper

Trying to use a constructor class to get a name and get a ID:

```
Public Student( String newName, String newId)
```

But it will not compile. I throws `Error: Syntax error on token "(", ; expected`.

```
/**
 * construct class
 * @parm String newName
 * @parm String newId
 */
public Student( String newName, String newId)
name = newName;
id = newId;

/**
* getName method that return instant varible name
*/
Public String getName()
```

Comment: public? That is the first letter lowercase?

Comment: That means you have an extra ")" somewhere.  Check your code.

Comment: It might help if you provide the number of the line the error occurs at.

Comment: You need a semicolon ';' at the end of the line too.

Answer (score 6):

public must be lower case

```
public Student( String newName, String new Id) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

`public`, `private`, `protected`, `static`, `class` are keywords on lower-case.